# Making changes on code doesn't reflect on django webapp

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I'm trying to edit my code on my django but somethings really weird is happening and i don't know what's happening. making me crazy af.

my chart code is inside static folder under **js/chart1.js**

then on my django template,
i have `<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/chart1.js' %}"></script>`

now i edited the **chart1.js** but it wont reflect.

1. i tried deleting staticfolder,
2. restarting server,
3. even deleting chart1.js under js directory

just as long as `<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/chart1.js' %}"></script>` is there, the chart still there even tho **chart1.js** dont exists anymore. i dont know where django getting its data for my graph.

can someone tell me whats happening? thanks!

Comment: Did you do this 'STATIC_URL = '/static/'' in settings.py and this '{% load static %}' in your template?

Comment: yes, btw fixed it. I cleared the browser cache. Thanks for answering

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force the browser to reload cached CSS and JavaScript files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118884/how-to-force-the-browser-to-reload-cached-css-and-javascript-files)

Answer (score 0):

Btw, I found a fixed. I cleared browser's cache.

Comment: I have had this problem before, also try CTRL + F5